# Invariant Violation: Calling pop to route for a route that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using NavigatorIOS and when the props that I am passing to the initial route change, I am trying to update them by resetting to the component you find below with the new updated props in "componentWillReceiveProps".

```
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
      this.refs.navigator.resetTo({
                    title: 'Home',
                    component: search,
                    backButtonTitle: 'Back',
                    passProps: {
                      api: nextProps.api,
                      slug: nextProps.slug
                   }
      });
    }
```

I am pretty sure I am not referencing the route correctly, but frankly I haven't found any useful resource regarding this problem.

Replace() does the job of updating the props, but I also want it to popToTop(). Replace and ResetTo both take a route object, so I don't understand why replace() works and resetTo() gives me this error.

This is my NavigatorIOS:

```
      <NavigatorIOS
            ref='navigator'
            initialRoute={
            {
              title: 'Home',
              component: search,
              backButtonTitle: 'Back',
                    passProps: {
                        api: this.props.api,
                        slug: this.props.slug
                     }

             }
           }
    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you declare something like:

```
var routes = this.refs.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
```

You can then pop to a route like this:

```
this.refs.navigator.popToRoute(routes[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the more manual but less limiting `React.Navigator` and `…navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack()`.

See Navigator docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

Comment: Do you think there is a specific reason behind that error?

Comment: NavigatorIOS is rotting code. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1403#issuecomment-106582753 & https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/476#issuecomment-101000692